# Adding a button to Navigator to exercise a choice

Tags: daml

Navigator contains a feature where users can define their own table views, see [DAML docs for Navigator](https://docs.daml.com/tools/navigator/index.html#customizable-table-views).

Is it possible to create a view where one column renders a button that, when clicked, immediately exercises a choice?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. The customized views allow you to render arbitrary React components, so let's create one to exercise a choice.

First, start with a working `frontend-config.js` file. The [DAML quickstart project](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html) contains one.

Then, make sure you import at least the following symbols at the top of the file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, DamlLfValue, withExercise } from '@da/ui-core';
```

Then, define the following top level values (for example, just below `export const version={...}`):

```js
// Create a React component to render a button that exercises a choice on click.
const ExerciseChoiceButtonBase = (props) => (
  <Button
    onClick={(e) => {
      props.exercise(props.contractId, props.choiceName, props.choiceArgument);
      e.stopPropagation();
    }}
  >
    {props.title}
  </Button>
)
ExerciseChoiceButtonBase.displayName = 'ExerciseChoiceButtonBase';

// Inject the `exercise` property to the props of the wrapped component.
// The value of that property is a convenience function to send a
// network request to exercise a choice.
const ExerciseChoiceButton = withExercise()(ExerciseChoiceButtonBase)
ExerciseChoiceButton.displayName = 'ExerciseChoiceButton';
```

Finally, use the following code in your table cell definition:

```js
{
        key: "id",
        title: "Action",
        createCell: ({rowData}) => {
          // Render our new component.
          // The contract ID and choice argument are computed from the current contract row.
          return ({
            type: "react",
            value: <ExerciseChoiceButton
              title='Transfer to issuer'
              contractId={rowData.id}
              choiceArgument={
                DamlLfValue.record(undefined, [
                  {label: 'newOwner', value: DamlLfValue.party(DamlLfValue.toJSON(rowData.argument).issuer)}
                ])
              }
              choiceName='Iou_Transfer'
            />
          });
        },
        sortable: true,
        width: 80,
        weight: 3,
        alignment: "left"
}
```

---

Another option would be create a React component where the `onClick` handler sends a REST API request using `fetch()`. Inspect the network traffic when exercising a choice through the Navigator UI in order to find out the format of the request.